# I need help with storefront theme shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, themes

I know I might be asking for a huge request and I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with my storefront theme on woocommerce.

I am planning to have a shop page similar to https://bloomscape.com/shop/featured/new-arrivals/

my current page is http://52.65.213.231/shop/ (it's a mess)

so what I actually want is to be able to access the HTML file and add a few divs and grids for the product title and price.

[image: from this]

[image: to this]

could anyone please help me.  I can give you access to the site if needed. Thanks

Comment: The HTML comes from a combination of the templates in your theme and the templates in WooCommerce itself (unless overridden by the theme). If you're using a theme you've downloaded you probably want to create a child theme where you can put template overrides for both of these: if you edit WooCommerce or a third-party theme then your edits will get lost when they update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where is that page located but I can help you with a practice that I do when I want to find the HTML code of a template file, Download your site (to use it locally) and then with the search tool from VS Code look for any specific class, or ID of the specific page that you want to edit